# login fails using php 7 and SQLserver

Tags: php, sql-server

im using xampp, php 7.2 using SQLServer as database but if fails to login. it return error that user or password missing. These are my codes. So whe ever i try to login shows the user is not found. i have tried to change some commands but still the problem is there.

im using xampp, php 7.2 using SQLServer as database but if fails to login. it return error that user or password missing. These are my codes. So whe ever i try to login shows the user is not found. i have tried to change some commands but still the problem is there.

```
 <?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $query = "SELECT [username],[password] FROM [test].[dbo].[user] WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}'";
     $params = array($username, $password);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result == true) {
        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            session_write_close();
            header('location: home');
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: index");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

anyone to help

Comment: What exactly is your error message - the one that is in your code ('user name and password not found'), or another from sqlsrv extension? Thanks.

Comment: Username missing
Password missing

Comment: Can you execute var_dump($conn) before $query = "SELECT ... "and post the  output?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i have found where the error was

```
//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
```

and replace it with

```
//Sanitize the POST values
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
```